# How to assign a limited number of prices to a large number of products based on three user options?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to allocate a limited number of prices to a large product selection based on three customization options. I have a database of 1200 product colors (subdivided into 4 categories), 3 different sizes of product, and 5 different types of products. Colors (depending on what sub-category they are in) have an effect on price. This equates to 16 different prices that must be assigned depending on what the user selects.

I'm struggling to get my mind around a good solution. Currently, I'm declaring each of the prices as variables and then doing a whole heap of if-else statements but feel like there must be a better way someone smarter can point me to.

```
var 20luxpas = 2,179.74;
var 20luxmed = 2,391.21;
var 20acrpas = 1,336.07;
var 20acrude = 1,805.64;
var 20acrmed = 1,384.05;
var 20acrdee = 1,546.22;
var 5ricpas = 632.28;
var 5ricmed = 606.74;
var 5peaude = 840.89;
var 5peapas = 681.59;
var 5peamed = 716.99;
var 5peadee = 761.16;
var 5gloude = 690.38;
var 5glopas = 548.80;
var 5glomed = 575.33;
var 5glodee = 619.57;

var selected = function (pricePicker) {
   if (selected == '5' (size), 'glo' (type), 'dee' (color))
       price = 5glodee;  
   } else if (selected == '5', 'pea', 'med') {
       price = 5peamed;
   } else if ........... etc
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that javascript does not support variables that start with a number nor thousand separators.

Comment: this should be db managed. if you are using any db add another table/object there and fetch it based on color and category

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like if-else or switch, you can define two arrays and use `findIndex`.

After parsing the text, you can build the variable name and access the value from object using `[]` accessor.

```js
const fields = 
{
  size: ['size-1','size-2','size-3'],
  color: ['color-1','color-2','color-3'],
  num: ['number-1','number-2','number-3']
};
const texts = 
{
  size: ['s1','s2','s3'],
  color: ['c1','c2','c3'],
  num: ['n1','n2','n3']
};

const input = {
  size: 'size-2',
  color: 'color-1',
  num: 'number-3'
}

const keyWords = ['size','color','num'];
const output = keyWords.map(k => {
  const idx = fields[k].findIndex(val => val === input[k]);
  if (idx > -1) {
    return texts[k][idx]
  } else {
    // error handling
  }
})

console.log(output.join(''));
```

Comment: thanks but a little confused - i have 3 user inputs ie color, type and size. Im assuming in the example s1/s2/s3 would be the price defined by the size input but I need it to be defined from 3 inputs?

Comment: @LexRidley Updated using 2D array,  probably you prefer this kind of answer I guess ?

Comment: thanks looks good just need to go over it to understand it completely will respond in a couple hours

Comment: so im confused by what you mean by 'fields' and 'text'. Is text the price?

Comment: @LexRidley `fields` means the user input and the `text` means segment for your variable name like '20', 'lux' and 'med'. Joining these segments together gives you the complete variable name and you can access the price via obj[complete_variable_name].

Comment: @user10093237 then what is const inputs referring to?

Comment: @user10093237 - ok i see what you have done and got it working, but don't understand what you mean by accessing the price from the obj?